# longitud de un json en angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Existe en angular 1.6 alguna funcion para saber el numero de registros que trae el json, lo quiero saber desde mi controlador, he utilizado
`$scope.count = Object.keys($scope.data).length`; pero me arroja 2, cuando mi json trae 8 registros, también utilice `$scope.count=$scope.data.length`; y me da 0.

```
$scope.tecnicos = TecnicoResource.query();
```

$scope.count = Object.keys($scope.tecnicos).length;
console.log($scope.count);

#### JSON

```
{ 
  "id_usuario": 5, 
  "nombre": "Oscar Javier", 
  "puesto": "Personal de soporte técnico", 
  "perfil_id": 6, 
  "empresa_id": 1, 
  "nombre_usuario": "ovivas", 
  "correo": "ovivas@gmail.com", 
  "activo": 1, 
  "deleted_at": null, 
  "created_at": "2016-07-26 17:50:38", 
  "updated_at": "2016-10-05 22:12:51", 
  "carga_trabajo": 0 
}
```

Comment: Podrias añadir el código que has estadpo utilizando para generar lo que requieres. Así alguien podria ayudarte.

Comment: Podrias poner tu JSON de ejemplo y la parte del codigo donde intentas obtener el resultado.

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales , este es el codigo
$scope.tecnicos = TecnicoResource.query();  
$scope.count = Object.keys($scope.tecnicos).length;
 console.log($scope.count);

y mi json trae 8 registros como este 
{
    "id_usuario": 5,
    "nombre": "Oscar Javier",
    "puesto": "Personal de soporte técnico",
    "perfil_id": 6,
    "empresa_id": 1,
    "nombre_usuario": "ovivas",
    "correo": "ovivas@gmail.com",
    "activo": 1,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2016-07-26 17:50:38",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-05 22:12:51",
    "carga_trabajo": 0
}

Comment: Buenas, probaste con Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)?

Comment: Disculpa, podrias agregar el código al menos para saber como estas trayendo ese **JSON** o si solo es de manera local la prueba.

Comment: Recibo mi json por medio de servicio Resource 
.controller('NuevaSolicitudCtrl',  function($scope,$rootScope, $location, $timeout,$window,TecnicoResource)
$scope.tecnicos = TecnicoResource.query();


});

Comment: Revisa la explicación que te deja abajo, tal vez te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que los objetos JSON solo son una colección de atributos, y por lo tanto, si quieres ver la longitud de un objeto como éste:

```
{ 
  "id_usuario": 5, 
  "nombre": "Oscar Javier", 
  "puesto": "Personal de soporte técnico", 
  "perfil_id": 6, 
  "empresa_id": 1, 
  "nombre_usuario": "ovivas", 
  "correo": "ovivas@gmail.com", 
  "activo": 1, 
  "deleted_at": null, 
  "created_at": "2016-07-26 17:50:38", 
  "updated_at": "2016-10-05 22:12:51", 
  "carga_trabajo": 0 
}
```

**La longitud sera 0**, sin embargo si quieres tener un array de objetos JSON, debería ser algo como esto:

```
tecnicos = [
    {
       nombre: Jose,
       apellido: Perez,
       edad: 18
    },
    {
       nombre: Carlos,
       apellido: Garcia,
       edad: 14
    },
    {
       nombre: Maria,
       apellido: Martinez,
       edad: 22
    }
]
```

Luego podrás hacer `tecnicos.length` sin problema.

Sin embargo, en el modo que tú estás declarando el JSON está mal, porque al tener comillas los nombres de atributos, el objeto deja de tener claves, por lo tanto deja de ser un objeto porque no tiene el formato **`(key, value)`** que maneja todo objeto.

Prueba quitándole las comillas así:

```
 $scope.tecnicos = { 
      id_usuario: 5, 
      nombre: "Oscar Javier", 
      puesto: "Personal de soporte técnico", 
      perfil_id: 6, 
      empresa_id: 1, 
      nombre_usuario: "ovivas", 
      correo: "ovivas@gmail.com", 
      activo: 1, 
      deleted_at: null, 
      created_at: "2016-07-26 17:50:38", 
      updated_at: "2016-10-05 22:12:51", 
      carga_trabajo: 0 
    }
```

En teoría, al corregir esto, deberías poder hacer sin problemas esto:

```
Object.keys($scope.tecnicos)
```

Y te retornaría un arreglo con todas las claves del objeto:

```
['id_usuario', 'nombre', 'puesto', 'perfil_id', 'empresa_id', 'nombre_usuario', 'correo', 'activo', 'deleted_at', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'carga_trabajo']
```

Y si a eso le haces `.length`:

```
$scope.count = Object.keys($scope.tecnicos).length;
console.log($scope.count); // console: 12
```

**El resultado es 12**